# jQuery Promises arguments failure callback undefined

Tags: jquery, promise

I am preparing some example material for a presentation which also covers the basics of jQuery promises and I am en-counting some strange behavior doing so. Hope you guys can help me out on this one.

I have the following code which works perfectly fine.

```
var getHTML1 = $.ajax({
        url: "jquerypromises.html",    
        type: "GET"
});

getHTML1.done(function(responseText, state, jqXHR){
    console.log("success from AJAX request with promises : getHTML1!");
});

getHTML1.fail(function(){
    console.log("error from AJAX request with promises : getHTML1!");
});

//this one will call the failure callback!!!!!!
var getHTML2 = 
$.ajax({
        url: "somenonexistingpage.html", //<== THIS WILL call the failure callback   
        type: "GET"
})
.then(
    function(){
        console.log("success from AJAX request with promises : getHTML2!");
    }
, 
    function(jqXHR, state){
        console.log("error from AJAX request with promises : getHTML2!");
    }
);
```

This code runs as espected for `getHTML1` the done handler is called and for `getHTML2` the failure handler is called.

Now when I add the following code below the code you see above.

```
$.when(getHTML1, getHTML2).then(
    function(response1, response2) {
        // both arguments are arrays with[responseText, "success", jqXHR] 
        console.log("Both promises went successfull");
        console.dir(response1);
        console.dir(response2);
    },
    function(jqXHR, status) {   
        console.log("One of both promises went wrong!");        
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(status);        
    }   
);
```

Again the proper handler is being called. In this case the failure callback is being called but all of it's arguments are undefined. Why is this?

Now when I remove the failure handler in the `then()` block the code for `getHTML2` becomes like this:

```
var getHTML2 = 
$.ajax({
        url: "somenonexistingpage.html", //<== THIS WILL call the failure callback   
        type: "GET"
})
.then(
    function(){
        console.log("success from AJAX request with promises : getHTML2!");
    }
);
```

Now everything works like expected, the failure handler in the second then() block is being called with the arguments filled.

Tested in Chrome with jQuery 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, that's because the documentation for [then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) says (emphasis mine):

> These filter functions can return **a new value** to be passed along to
>   the promise's `.done()` or `.fail()` callbacks, or they can return another
>   observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its
>   resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks. If
>   the filter function used is `null`, or not specified, the promise will
>   be resolved or rejected **with the same values as the original**.

So you can either return a single value from the fail filter, which is not what you want (you want two values) or omit the fail filter altogether to have `then()` pass the same values as the original promise.

If you want to implement a fail filter that returns more than one value, you can return a new Deferred object that you immediately reject with these values:

```
var getHTML2 = $.ajax({
    url: "somenonexistingpage.html", //<== THIS WILL call the failure callback   
    type: "GET"
}).then(function() {
    console.log("success from AJAX request with promises : getHTML2!");
}, function(jqXHR, state) {
    console.log("error from AJAX request with promises : getHTML2!");
    return $.Deferred().reject(jqXHR, state);
});
```